# Executing Stored procedure without Deadlock and Application without hanging tight

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, amazon-rds

I am executing a stored procedure which has to update regular basis on job scheduler at 12.01 AM of server time without any deadlock or any disturbances.

The Procedure will evaluate complete rows around 15000 records for calculation and it has to be updated and it is taking 2 minutes to complete the execution.

So I have added this below code to avoid deadlock while in execution of this procedure until it gets completed.

```
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH

exec [ProcedureName]

SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW
```

Is this code will cause any problem in DB Operation or an application performance ?

Note: I tested this with multiple persons to get access the application grids at the same time I have executed the query. It is not affecting anything regarding performance and my requirement also solved. But still want to know more about dependencies of DB. Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you opt query hints for one `stored proc`, there is chance for dead locks happening for any parallel processes.

You may not notice no performance hit, as other queries may be suspended. `sp_who2`.It is a good idea to trace for any blocked processes while execution of the proc

```
    SELECT * FROM dbo.sysprocesses WHERE spid IN 
     (SELECT blocked FROM dbo.sysprocesses where blocked <> 0)
```

If you do not see any blocked processes, check for any dead locks at the time of execution.

```
SELECT  L.request_session_id AS SPID, 
    DB_NAME(L.resource_database_id) AS DatabaseName,
    O.Name AS LockedObjectName, 
    P.object_id AS LockedObjectId, 
    L.resource_type AS LockedResource, 
    L.request_mode AS LockType,
    ST.text AS SqlStatementText,        
    ES.login_name AS LoginName,
    ES.host_name AS HostName,
    TST.is_user_transaction as IsUserTransaction,
    AT.name as TransactionName,
    CN.auth_scheme as AuthenticationMethod
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks L
    JOIN sys.partitions P ON P.hobt_id = L.resource_associated_entity_id
    JOIN sys.objects O ON O.object_id = P.object_id
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ES ON ES.session_id = L.request_session_id
    JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions TST ON ES.session_id = TST.session_id
    JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions AT ON TST.transaction_id = AT.transaction_id
    JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections CN ON CN.session_id = ES.session_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CN.most_recent_sql_handle) AS ST
WHERE   resource_database_id = db_id()
```

It worth of looking at perfmon counters and any slow running queries at execution.
The question of debate is why we want to use `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH`, did you looked at transaction isolation levels set on the database.
Switching to `read committed snapshot isolation level` would really reduce need to use these query hints. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server.

This query will tell u status of the isolation level in your database.

```
select name
        , s.snapshot_isolation_state
        , snapshot_isolation_state_desc
        , is_read_committed_snapshot_on
        , recovery_model
        , recovery_model_desc
        , collation_name
    from sys.databases s
```

Comment: >>>check for any dead locks at the time of execution:....<<< Do you really think that someone is able to monitor deadlocks this way? Do you know how SQL Server resolves dedlocks?

Comment: I have had the same question in the real scenario, I have set up Email alert and monitored. Ofcos all of us know SQL heals deadlocks itself and i believe it is important to find the victim of dead lock, table hit and so on..

Comment: Any deadlock will be resolved PRIOR that you even hit F5 to execute your code

Comment: That is obvious, how about parallel process when they are suspended as a victim of dead locks. Do we look through trace flags 1204 and 1222 ?. Happy to get your input mate

Comment: >>> how about parallel process when they are suspended as a victim of dead locks<<< Victims of dedlocks are NOT SUSPENDED. they are rolled back

Comment: I have traced it over a period using traces and alerts , gives clear indication that they are suspended and followed best practices . They will be rolled back if they are committed if i am not wrong . >>>>>Any deadlock will be resolved PRIOR that you even hit F5 to execute your code<<<  I guess this doesn't support for parallel processes

Comment: Are you talking about intra-query deadlocks?